# Lazy loading with multiple scrollview and dynamic images

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

I having a hard time with this one and would appreciate any help, my problem is that I'm building a multiple image carousel in a tableview it contains custom cell with scroll view in each of them the scrollview display images from xml fetched thru the internet which means uiimageview is added runtime as a scrollview subview. I want to lazy load these images so it will not take up too much memory. The samples that I've found only uses 1 scrollview and predefined image count.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend this github project
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage