# display lazy image loading scrollview for disply indivial image loading by activity indicator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

how can i display images by lazyimageloading in scrollview can anyone please suggest answer

---

```
xview = 21;//30
yview = 21;
yscroll = 150;//200
h=1;
NSLog(@"arr count %d",[filelistarr count]);

for(int s=0;s<[filelistarr count];s++)
{
    obj=[filelistarr objectAtIndex:s];
    scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, yscroll);
    if(h%4 == 0)
    {
        xview=21;
        h=1;
        yview=yview+120;
        //yscroll=yscroll+20;
    }

    imgbtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    imgbtn.frame = CGRectMake(xview, yview, 80, 80);
    imgbtn.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    imgbtn.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    imgbtn.tag=(s+1);

}
```

- the image set button correctly but how to set lazy image loading please help me....

Comment: `}` - that was bugging me. BTW, what's with the backticks?

Answer (score 0):

see this http://lazyloadinginuiscrollviewiniphone.blogspot.in/2011/12/iphone-uiscrollview-lazy-image-loading.html i hope it will fulfill your all requirement.
Also there is similar type of question see following links as well,

1) [Uiscrollview lazy loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659650/uiscrollview-lazy-loading)

2)[Lazy loading with multiple scrollview and dynamic images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283513/lazy-loading-with-multiple-scrollview-and-dynamic-images)

3)[iOS UIScrollView Lazy Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750164/ios-uiscrollview-lazy-loading)